# Ноутбук зависает намертво при просмотре видео на Mint/Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

При просмотре видео, минут через 5, ноутбук просто зависает намертво, единственное, что спасает - долгое удержание кнопки выключения. Ноутбук Asus X553MA. Данная проблема наблюдается на mint и ubuntu, а на windows 8.1/10 и debian ее нет. С чем это может быть связано, и как это решить?

P.S. Если вам нужны выводы каких-то команд, не ругайтесь, что их нет, я плохо в этом разбираюсь и не могу знать, какие команды вам могут понадобиться.

Спасибо.

Comment: Начните с домашней работы, а именно проигрывателя, формата видео и аудио, какие библиотеки у вас стоят и реально используются (как source, так и sink). Пока вопрос в стиле "у меня подземный стук!"

Comment: Видео зависают в любом формате, будь то скачанные в любом формате фильмы, будь то видео с ютуба, будь то просмотр фильмов онлайн. А насчет библиотек я не знаю, что Вам ответить. Как посмотреть? Вообще, я ничего не устанавливал на данный момент, кроме хрома.

Comment: На этом ноуте только интегрированное видео? (то есть, нет nvidia или другой дискретной видеокарты?). Судя по сайту асуса так и есть. Поэтому, скорее всего там проблема с кодеками. Сложно что то советовать, но попробуйте запустить с флешки/livecd ubuntu и протестить. И в любом случае, лучше обновить все пакеты.

Comment: А зачем тестировать с livecd ubuntu, если я и так знаю, что видео на убунту зависают? Вообще, пакеты разве не должны быть обновленными, раз я только что поставил минт? Меня просто настроживает, что на дебиане такой проблемы и в помине нет, и я им достаточно долго пользовался.

Comment: @KoVadim, уверен, что проблема вовсе не с кодеками, раз любые видео вешают машину. Скорее всего проблема со стороны sink, а не source.

Comment: У вас стоит пакет с названием типа *libva-intel-driver*? В нём были проблемы. И напишите в конце концов техническую инфрмацию (хотя бы начните с видеоплеера, продолжив выводом информации о паре видеофайлов с действительно разными кодеками: `ffprobe` вам в помощь)

Comment: @Straik32423 > "Пакеты разве не должны быть обновленными, раз я только что поставил минт?" - Нет, не должны. Для обновления используйте `sudo apt update` и затем `sudo apt dist-upgrade`.

Comment: @Straik32423 "livecd ubuntu, если я и так знаю, что видео на убунту зависают" - надо быть строго уверенным, что там ничего нет дополнительного. "я только что поставил минт" - обновления выходят очень часто. 
 0andriy - сейчас драйвера такие пошли, что используют возможности железа и большая часть кодека внутри железа/драйвера. Поэтому да, может и "видеодрайвер" (я специально в кавычках написал)

Answer (score 4):

Раз система тормозит (скорее всего - именно тормозит, а не умерла), то это означает, что полностью исчерпан некий ресурс. Наиболее вероятно - память. Чаще всего так бывает, когда некий процесс начинает бесконечно размножаться, не завершая дочерние процессы.

Гипотеза о вирусе(!) ничего, кроме улыбки у меня не вызывает. Вот уже 25 лет работаю исключительно в люнихе (в винде - в "Цивилизацию" играю) и за всё это время не видел ни одного вируса. И не слышал. Хотя никаких антивирусов у меня не стоит.

Попробуйте сделать так:

1. Надо выяснить, кто КОНКРЕТНО вешает систему. Для этого , после "зависания" проигрывателя, нажимаем комбинацию "Ctrl/Alt/F1". Поскольку комп тормозит, то (скорее всего) придётся жать довольно долго.
2. Должно открыться окно консольного терминала. Скорее всего, там тоже будет отрабатываться нажатие на клавиши в час по чайной ложке.
3. Надо будет ввести логин и пароль.
4. После этого введите команду *top*. Вам покажут список процессов, работающих в настоящее время, по порядку их прожорливости.
5. Возможно два варианта:
6. В верхней строке расположен процесс, который жрёт 100% проца или памяти. Убейте его и комп оживёт.
7. Особо прожорливого процесса нет, но есть огромное количество копий одного и того же процесса. Так бывает с некоторыми программами, которые идут в иНет и натыкаются там на "закольцованные" ссылки. Прибейте эти процессы, скачайте файл на комп и попытайтесь воспроизвести его локально.
8. Далее - по обстоятельствам...

Есть более простой вариант: сначала откройте на компе терминал, выполните команду *top*, а уже потом - запускайте проигрыватель. Так Вы сразу увидите, кто жрёт ресурсы. И в момент зависания компа перед вами будет полня картинка.

Comment: Вчера я попробовал открыть терминал и видео сразу. Целый фильм проиграл, не зависнув. Сегодня я запустил фильм, а через пять минут он завис. Я нажал нужную комбинацию клавиш и подождал около двух часов, но терминал так и не появился. Потом я опять открыл терминал и top, но, опять же, видео не зависло. Без понятия, с чем это связано.

Comment: @Straik32423 Я правильно понимаю, что воспроизведение ОДНОГО и того же видео ОДНИМ и тем же проигрывателем у вас идёт успешно на одних ОС и неудачно на других (mint и ubuntu)? Именно - ОДНОГО и того же?  Тогда далее - это видео лежит на локальном диске, или Вы его смотрите непосредственно из иНета? И последнее уточнение: я правильно понимаю, что если запустить этот невезучий проигрывтаель на это файл в одиночестве, то система зависает, а если открыто окно терминала с командой top, то всё нормально?

Comment: Да. Только я смотрю онлайн. В обоих случаях через хром.

Comment: *Только я смотрю онлайн* - я предполагаю, что дело как раз в этом. Можно как-то скачать любой файл с таким же кодеком и проиграть локально?

Answer (score 0):

Данная проблема решилась у меня после увеличения SWAP - значение должно быть не меньше чем реальный объем оперативки! Так же исчезли зависания во время спящего режима!
Все остальные способы вплоть до полного отключения дискретной Nvidia видеокарты - не помогали! А настройки SWAP помогли!